# Filebeat: 0 Documents After Index Rollover

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, elk

I am experiencing an issue with Filebeat where, after an index rollover, the new index shows 0 documents, and no data seems to be indexed. Here are the details of my setup:

**Filebeat Configuration:**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
multiline.type: pattern
multiline.pattern: ^d{4}-d{2}-d{2} d{2}:d{2}:d{2}
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.ilm.enabled: false
setup.template.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
setup.kibana:
  host: '$elk_host_public_ip:5601'
  username: 'elastic'
  password: 'password'
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://elasticsearch-host:9200"]
  username: 'elastic'
  password: 'password'
  index: "rollover-7.17.8-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}-000001"
http.enabled: true
http.port: 5067
http.host: localhost
monitoring.enabled: true
processors:
  - add_host_metadata:
      when.not.contains.tags: forwarded
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 3
  permissions: 0640
seccomp:
  default_action: allow 
  syscalls:
  - action: allow
    names:
    - rseq
name: 'project_name'
tags: ['project_name']
' > /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml
```

**ILM Policy is:-**

```
PUT _ilm/policy/rollover
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "min_age": "0ms",
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_age": "10m",
            "max_docs": 10
          },
          "set_priority": {
            "priority": 100
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "10m",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {
            "delete_searchable_snapshot": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rollover is successfully completed but there is no data in the index (docs - 0 , storage - 424b).